# FBConnect for iPhone: sessionDidNotLogin, sessionDidLogout, session didLogin not called the second time I load a view

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

My problem is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056305/fbconnect-sessiondidlogin-never-called-starting-from-the-second-time-the-user-t), however I am posting a new one, as the answer to the aforementioned does not seem to solve my problem.

I have a multiview application - the first view is where the user logs in to Facebook, and the second where he picks an image and uploads it there. The first time the app runs, everything works fine, however if I return to the login view and press logout, then any calls to `sessionDidNotLogin`, `sessionDidLogout` or `session didLogin` don't seem to work.

I found out that the first time, if I `NSLog(@"%@",session.delegates);` I have 2; my LoginViewController and the FBLoginButton. However, apart from that first time, the same log prints only the LoginViewController and not the FBLoginButton. I guess this is connected somehow, but I don't know how to solve it.

Do I have to manually add the FBLoginButton to the session delegates, or I'm doing something else wrong here?

Thank you for any help/suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, thanks to [a post from the Facebook developers forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=56051).
Everytime a view was loaded, I was creating a new session instance (even though I thought that it would be a singleton and the library should have taken care of it).

So, in order to make this work:

```
  fbSession = [FBSession session];
  if (!fbSession) {
    fbSession = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];
  } else {
    [[fbSession delegates] addObject:self];
  }
```